# Laravel file upload name is incorrect

Tags: laravel

If i do the following with file example.jpg the storage file is getting a random name. How can i give it the example.jpg name?

```
Storage::disk('local')->put('test', $request->file('file') )
```

This works, but how can i specify a disk?

```
    $file = request()->file('files');
    $file->storeAs('test',$request->file('files')->getClientOriginalName());
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/filesystem#storing-files),

> If you would not like a file name to be automatically assigned to your stored file, you may use the  storeAs method, which receives the path, the file name, and the (optional) disk as its arguments:

```
$file->storeAs('test', $request->file('files')->getClientOriginalName(), 'local');
```

Comment: error, Exception Impossible to create the root directory "/home/vagrant/Code/xxx/storage/app/test/xxxx.jpg".

Comment: does the storage directory has write permission?

Comment: i deleted the previous test folder, now the following is created, test/example.jpg/i6fRmKhvhIfuLuBBmXvUq32Xuu8fIIbmwYoywkrX.jpeg , so same problem as mentioned...

Comment: sorry, it is `storeAs` please try again

Comment: I allready had mentioned in my post, this works,     $file = request()->file('files');
    $file->storeAs('test',$request->file('files')->getClientOriginalName()); But how to specify the disk?

Comment: the disk is passed as an third argument to the method